# Localizar palavras duplicadas sem selecionar um por uma

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

No Sublime Text eu sei que posso encontrar palavras duplicadas se eu selecionar uma por uma como mostra a imagem:

[image: Item selecionado]

Quando seleciono a palavra Item o Sublime destaca as outras referências.

Existe a possibilidade de localizar palavras duplicadas sem ter que selecionar uma por uma?

Answer (score 2):

Se o seu Sublime estiver com a configuração padrão, usando o `Ctrl + D` será selecionada cada ocorrência da sua seleção atual uma à uma.

Para selecionar todas de uma vez, use o `Ctrl + F`. Abrirá a barra de busca na parte inferior do programa e você poderá clicar em `Find All` ou `Alt + Enter`, que selecionará todas as ocorrências da palavra buscada.

Dica: Com o `Ctrl + F`, se a palavra que deseja-se buscar já estiver selecionada, o Sublime entende que é ela que deve ser buscada e já 'pré-seta' a busca com o conteúdo selecionado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta amigo, mas isso eu já sei, o que eu preciso é que o Sublime me mostre referências repetidas sem precisar selecionar uma delas. Ex: digamos que meu documento tem a palavra "text" e "number" em vários lugares, gostaria que o Sublime indicasse que essas duas palavras estão no documento mais de uma vez sem que eu precise selecionar a palavra "text" ou "number".

Comment: Então vc busca uma forma que o sublime marque todas as palavras que tem mais de uma ocorrência?

Comment: isso mesmo, e preciso que ele faça isso sem precisar selecionar nenhuma das ocorrências.